# Directx mesh rotation in car

Tags: c++

I downloaded a model of car in X file.
Now I wont to render it and rotation the wheels to show that the car and go forward and
the problem is that the wheels rotate around the car canter instead of their center.
how can I fixed this problem?
thank you very much!
I do not think I need to show the source code because it is irrelevant.

Comment: When transforming the wheels, first rotate them and then translate them to their position. Does this help?

Comment: that what I am doing but the wheels position set by the position of the whole mesh

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with X meshs. Your description just sounds like your wheels were first translated to their position and then rotated. Their center needs to be in 0,0,0 so the rotation doesn't change the position.

Comment: the center is the center of the car mesh